Will self-contained .NET Core on Ubuntu change the state of the OS or other systems?
Will a self-contained .NET Core ASP.NET webapp on Ubuntu 22.04 change the state of the OS (or other systems) in any way?

Will it mess with any configs or ini files outside its own directory?
Will it change files outside its own directory?
If I delete the directory containing the .NET core app, will the OS be identical to how it was before I deployed the .NET core files?
Will it change the state/operation/config of any services/daemons like Apache, etc?

I want to run a .NET core webapp on my Ubuntu server, but that server already has many important applications and websites running on the LAMP stack. I'm nervous about .NET core touching/disrupting any of them, mainly because I don't understand how exactly .NET core runs on Linux, what all it does, what it touches, etc.

Why do you expect it to affect things? Self-contained app will come with build-in set of dependencies and should not require anything outside.


https://github.com/Sysinternals/ProcMon-for-Linux A tool like Process Monitor tells you more. 2) The web app itself is more likely to alter the system (like writing temp files and leaving logs) than .NET itself. 3) You should rely on modern things like Docker to isolate important applications, and only that removes your fears and nervousness.


Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Don't worry, unless you've explicitly "coded" a thing to modify the system, your web app won't do that. .NET is a framework. Until you're running self-contained .NET code or publishing your code to Native AOT, it won't make any modifications outside what you implement.

"Until you're running" - but OP states that I want to run a .NET core webapp =)

Well, I didn't speak generally. As I said .NET is a framework. But thanks for clarification

Thanks everyone, this really gives me a clearer picture!
